# How align in horizontal the menu?

Tags: css, menu, alignment

I'm trying to align my text (horizontal) but my efforts are not working

```
.menu{
    background: hsla(290,60%,70%,0.3);
    list-style: none;
}
.menu li{
        width: 200px;
}
.menu li a{
    padding: 8px 16px;
    float:center;
    display: inline;
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu li a:hover{

    background-color: hsla(200,100%,40%,0.2);
}
```

Comment: There is no `float: center`. Try using `display: flex;` on the `.menu` div.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: hsla(290,60%,70%,0.3);
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
.menu li{
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu li a:hover{
  background-color: hsla(200,100%,40%,0.2);
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="/">thing</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">stuff</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">things</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">stuffs</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">thingsstuff</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try! :D

Answer (score -1):

Check this Demo. You have used  `float:center;` use `float:left` against it. It's should work.

[Demo](https://codepen.io/rajibchandrakarmaker/pen/GBELgL/)

Comment: if it helped you then why negative vote and I am confused why I get negative vote. I would like to know the answer because it's demotivated me to give the questions answer. Thanks

Comment: I think since the question received a negative vote, any answers automatically get negative. Mine did as well :(